# How to run a function in the controls of Storybook?

Tags: javascript, function, controls, add-on, storybook

I got a component which has a button that can be clicked. It got its props, here it go:

```
...
<Button id="buttonAddTreatments" 
   color={colorOfTheButton}
   variant="contained" 
   onClick={onAddClick}
   disabled={disableButton}>
     <AddIcon></AddIcon>
</Button>
...
```

Then, when I load it in the Storybook, I try to type a function on the `onClick`, with the Controls add-on, just like this:

[image]

Unfortanily, it doesn't work at all. What I'm doing wrong?